# filterNotNull on Kotlin List with generic type

Tags: generics, kotlin

This is working :

```
val values: List<String>  = listOf("a", null, "b").filterNotNull()
```

This is not working :

```
fun <A> nonNullValues(values: List<A?>): List<A> = values.filterNotNull()
```

The compiler complains about generic types :

```
Error:(8, 63) Kotlin: Type parameter bound for T in fun <T : kotlin.Any> kotlin.collections.Iterable<T?>.filterNotNull(): kotlin.collections.List<T>
 is not satisfied: inferred type A is not a subtype of kotlin.Any
```

This one is working :

```
fun <A: Any> nonNullValues(values: List<A?>): List<A> = values.filterNotNull()
```

Could someone please explain me why I need to tell the compiler that A is a subtype of Any? I was thinking every type was a subtype of Any...

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [the Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#upper-bounds):

> The default upper bound (if none specified) is `Any?`

This means that the problematic declaration is equivalent to:

```
fun <A:Any?> nonNullValues(values: List<A?>): List<A> = values.filterNotNull()
```

The `nonNullValues` method declares to return a list of **nullable items of type `A`** whereas [`filterNotNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-not-null.html) returns a list of **non nullable items of type `A`**. Hence a mismatch and a compiler error.